# How to find the hierarchical dependency graph for a set of R packages?

Tags: r, dependencies

Given a set of R packages I would like to find out which ones come hierarchically first in a dependency graph.

Kontext:
The motivation behind this comes from wanting to create a system setup (via Docker) in which I can manually specify all packages and their versions and install (via `remotes::install_version` package) them with `dependencies=FALSE` and `upgrade='never'` so that I actually get what I request. This will only work if everything is installed in the right order.

I am answering with my own solution but I'm also interested in other ones that may be better.

Comment: The `pak` package does things like that.

Comment: As Docker is Linux, you can use Ubuntu and [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) gets you all of this via `apt`, more reliably, faster and easier than alternate approaches that lack the system integration that [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) offers.  And if you start from the `rocker/r2u` container as I do _e.g._ for CI then everything "just works".  (And we could reconstruct the graph of depencies because the `RcppAPT` package can talk to `apt`.  Or if just as the R level is good enough then your approach via `tools::package_dependencies` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tools::package_dependencies()` to retrieve all dependencies and then iteratively construct the hierarchy.

```r
# packages of interest
packages <- c("haven", "tibble", "rlang", "hms", "vctrs")

dependencies <- tools::package_dependencies(packages, db = available.packages())

hierarchy <- c()
c <- 0
while(length(dependencies) > 0) {
  all_package_names <- names(dependencies)
  c <- c + 1
  # show current iteration
  print(c)
  for(i in 1:length(dependencies)) {
    curr_pack <- names(dependencies[i])
    curr_deps <- dependencies[[i]]
    if(! any(curr_deps %in% all_package_names)) {
      hierarchy <- c(hierarchy, curr_pack)
    }
  }
  dependencies[hierarchy] <- NULL
}

hierarchy
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rang` library includes functionality to do this.

```r
library(rang) # 0.2.1
graph <- resolve("callr")
df <- convert_edgelist(graph)
rev(unique(df$to))
```

The reversed `unique()` of the `to` column in the `data.frame` coming out of `convert_edgelist()` returns the order in which the dependency packages of - in this case `callr` - need to be installed.